# Python3: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

The following code gives the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment`. I looked the similar issue in other stackoverflow question but they say about dealing with global variables but I don't find my issue has any global variable `labels` referring to.

```
def get_tags(predicted_list, threshold, labels):
    mlb = [(i1, c1) for i1, c1 in enumerate(multilabel.classes_)]
    temp_list = sorted(
        [(i, c) for i, c in enumerate(list(predicted_list))],
        key=lambda x: x[1],
        reverse=True,
    )
    tag_list = [item1 for item1 in temp_list if item1[1] >= threshold]
    tags = [
        item[1] for item2 in tag_list[:labels] for item in mlb if item2[0] == item[0]
    ]
    return tags

def label_prediction(num_clicks, text, threshold_value, preprocess_func, label_value):
    if text is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        if num_clicks:
            params = ["remove_digits", "remove_stopwords", "text_lemmatization"]
            dict_params = {param: True for param in params}
            preprocess_text = preprocess(text, **dict_params)
            transformed_text = tfidf.fit_transform([preprocess_text])
            prediction = classifier.predict_proba(transformed_text)
            labels= f"Predicted labels:{get_tags(prediction[0],threshold_value,label_value)}"
    return labels
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Which error are you asking about: the one in the title or the one in the text?

Comment: I think both are same.

Comment: They WERE not the same before you edited the question.

Comment: labels or tags ? . For both shouldn't be no problem with the exact code you give

Comment: yeah that was typo...reload the page.

Comment: Please post the full (or last 10 lines) of the traceback.

Comment: What is `PreventUpdate` ?

Comment: exception handling of Dash Plotly.

Comment: It looks as though `num_clicks` is not validating (to True) therefore `labels` is not getting set before the return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only create the local variable `labels` if `num_clicks` is true in the function `label_prediction`, but you return this local variable in any case. Thus, if you call the function `label_prediction` with `num_clicks` being `False`, you return a variable that was never created, hence the error message.

**Edit**: Since you don't want to return anything when `num_clicks` is false, you can just modify the last line of your if with `return f"Predicted labels:{get_tags(prediction[0],threshold_value,label_value)}"`, and remove the return at the end of your function.

Another solution would be to just initialize `labels` with `None` at the beginning of the function.

**Solution 1**

```
def label_prediction(num_clicks, text, threshold_value, preprocess_func, label_value):
    if text is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        if num_clicks:
            params = ["remove_digits", "remove_stopwords", "text_lemmatization"]
            dict_params = {param: True for param in params}
            preprocess_text = preprocess(text, **dict_params)
            transformed_text = tfidf.fit_transform([preprocess_text])
            prediction = classifier.predict_proba(transformed_text)
            return f"Predicted labels:{get_tags(prediction[0],threshold_value,label_value)}"
```

**Solution 2**

```
def label_prediction(num_clicks, text, threshold_value, preprocess_func, label_value):
    labels = None
    if text is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        if num_clicks:
            params = ["remove_digits", "remove_stopwords", "text_lemmatization"]
            dict_params = {param: True for param in params}
            preprocess_text = preprocess(text, **dict_params)
            transformed_text = tfidf.fit_transform([preprocess_text])
            prediction = classifier.predict_proba(transformed_text)
            labels = f"Predicted labels:{get_tags(prediction[0],threshold_value,label_value)}"
    return labels
```

Comment: so what should be the way around?

Comment: What do you want to return when `num_clicks` is false?

Comment: In this case you can just modify the last line of your if with `return f"Predicted labels:{get_tags(prediction[0],threshold_value,label_value)}"`, and remove the return at the end of your function.

Comment: Another solution would be to just initialize `labels` with `None` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: now the actual click isn't returning anything with first solution.

Comment: Do you mean nothing or `None`? In both cases it is another problem

Comment: I mean nothing.